# Wordpress Woocommerce try on service for product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a eCommerce site and my client want to product on rent functionality.

for e.g : On Add To Cart page a product has delivery + return date on add to cart page

Suppose I have select date from 24 to 28 and I would product on try on specific date so when I add to cart product then trial product also added with charge.

E.g Screenshot attached:

[image]

Comment: This question requires a very long answer or recommendation of plugins. It is not very suitable for Stack Overflow. That said you could try that plugin -
 https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/booking-and-rental-system-woocommerce/ or https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-bookings/ or https://www.tychesoftwares.com/store/premium-plugins/rental-system-addon-woocommerce-booking-appointment-plugin/.

Comment: Pretty sure it's not bookings that's needed. Sounds more like [Product Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Comment: @helgatheviking Product add-ons and not bookings? Maybe so. I put about as much effort into my comment as OP did with his/her question.

Comment: @JamesJones Yeah it looks like Add-Ons to me. But that is 100% fair. I voted to close the question but because there is a bounty it cannot be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Woocommerce Product Add-ons](https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/)

The Product Add-Ons extension allows you to add additional paid (or free) options to your products using several field types including radio buttons, checkboxes, drop-down fields, custom text inputs and more.